# How is Battle Activity calculated?

Tags: war-thunder

Battle activity is a percentage that is shown at the end of a battle.

During the winter holidays, there's a contest that, if you win 5 battles with more than 80% of activity, will let you join the CBT of the naval forces.

My question is: What is this Battle Activity? How is it calculated? How can you easily have more than 80?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this forum thread](https://forum.warthunder.com/index.php?/topic/231527-battle-activity/), Battle Activity is calculated in the following manner:

> It takes into account your battle time and the points you've earned. If you have the most points in your team and you were in the battle all the time you get 100%. So, its A x B where
>
> A is the leader point divided by your point
>
> B is the full battle time divided by your battle time.

Thus, it looks like to get a Battle Activity of over 80 over 5 battles, your goal would be to be as high up on the leaderboard for your team as possible and to stay in the battle for the entire duration.

Comment: Yeah.. seems that I missed that forum thread while googling Battle activity. Many thanks

Comment: Actually not. Last game I was active in the battle from the start to win. I was first in team with 9 kills and some asists. But I dont have 90% to finish my mission. This is reason, why Im trying to find this calculating :D